# How to get values from client.users.fetch(id) in discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have a bot that takes a mention and returns some user information:

```
bot.on('message', async message => {
    let usr = bot.users.fetch(message.replace('<@!', '').replace('>', ''));
    message.channel.send(`id: ${usr.id}\nname: ${usr.username}`);
});
```

However, the bot returns undefined for both values. I have logged the user object, and revieved

```
Promise {
    User { 
        id: '',
        username: '',
        bot: false,
        discriminator: '',
        avatar: '',
        lastMessageId: '',
        LastMessage: '',
    }
}
```

The values are different, but the objects are the same. I tried using `usr.Promise.User.value`, `usr.User.value`, and `usr.Promise.value` with no luck. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `message.mentions.users.first()`:

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
    let usr = message.mentions.users.first();
    message.channel.send(`id: ${usr.id}\nname: ${usr.username}`);
});
```

It's a totally different way to do what you want and it's better. It also avoids your "promise" problem so it's not really an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It returns a `Promise` so you need to use `await` or `.then` to get its resolved value:

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
    let usr = await bot.users.fetch(message.replace('<@!', '').replace('>', ''));
    message.channel.send(`id: ${usr.id}\nname: ${usr.username}`);
});
```

**OR**:

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {
    bot.users.fetch(message.replace('<@!', '').replace('>', '')).then((usr) => {
        message.channel.send(`id: ${usr.id}\nname: ${usr.username}`);
    });
});
```

You can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to learn more about promises.

Comment: I am now encountering an issue where if I replace the !, <@ and > don't get replaced

Comment: I added a new answer